# How do I stop Git Extensions checking for updates?

Tags: windows, git

Whenever I open Git Extensions, it tells me there is an update available. How do I stop this check, without installing the latest version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been looking for a way to do this too -- my best guess so far is:

1. Close GitExtensions
2. Open this file in a text editor:

   Windows:
   `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\GitExtensions\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.settings`

   Linux:
   `~/.config/GitExtensions/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.settings`
3. Look for `LastUpdateCheck` and set the value to some date far in the future, e.g. change the year to 2037

I don't know for sure that this works long-term, but so far it hasn't nagged me since I did this.

Comment: 2022, can't believe its not exposed to UI yet

Answer (score 0):

This option to disable update checks was added in by [this PR](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/5505).

Go to `Tools` > `Settings` > `Git Extensions` > `Advanced`, and uncheck "Check for updates weekly" under "Updates"

[image: Setting menu screenshot]